# How would I define the whether it is disk or washer?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help?
Imagine this is the question:
 Use the Disk/Washer method to find the volume of the solid created by rotating the region bounded by y = 2x – 4, y = 0, and x = 3 about the Y axis.
Now how would I know that which formula I have to use?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, it helps to add details of your thoughts and what you have tried to aid responders and help them better understand your issue. Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A washer is what is left when you cut a disk out of a disk. If your volume has a hole on axis, you need a washer. In your example, at $y=0$,the region extends from $x=2$ to $x=3$, so is away from the center of revolution, the $y$ axis, so you need washers.

Comment: When should I use disk?

Comment: You should use the disk when the region of integration goes all the way to the axis of rotation.  Say you had the volume formed by rotating the region below $y=1-x$, above $y=0$, and left of $x=0$ around the $y$ axis.  Now the region touches the $y$ axis, so you use a disk.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try sketching the area you're rotating. In this case, it'll look like a triangle starting at with corners at the points $(2, 0), (3, 0)$ and $(3, 2)$.